# shipment rest API not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping, rest-api

**Endpoint**

**POST** `http://<host>/rest/default/V1/order/3/ship`

where 3 is the order id.

**Headers**

```
Content-Type application/json

Authorization Bearer <administrator token>
```

**Request Body:**

```
{
"items": [
{
"extensionAttributes": {},
"orderItemId": 96,

"qty": 1
}
],
"notify": true,
"appendComment": true,
"comment": {
"comment": "Tracking URl : www.tackingurl.com/id?123456789",
"isVisibleOnFront": 0
},
"tracks": [
{
"trackNumber": "1234567890",
"title": "SHIPPING",
"carrier_code": "shipping"
}
]
}
```

**Response:**

```
[2018-03-09 08:29:06] report.CRITICAL: ReflectionException: Class array does not exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\vendor\magento\framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor.php:149
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\vendor\magento\framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor.php(149): ReflectionClass->__construct('array')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\vendor\magento\framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor.php(319): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->_createFromArray('array', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\vendor\magento\framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor.php(119): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->convertValue(Array, 'array[]')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\app\code\Local\AuthAclOverride\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver.php(121): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->process('Magento\\Sales\\A...', 'execute', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Controller\Rest.php(299): Local\AuthAclOverride\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver->resolve()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Controller\Rest.php(216): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\var\generation\Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#11 {main}

Next Exception: Report ID: webapi-5aa245d25da78; Message: Class array does not exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\vendor\magento\framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor.php:195
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\vendor\magento\framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(ReflectionException))
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\vendor\magento\module-webapi\Controller\Rest.php(219): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(ReflectionException))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\var\generation\Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Local\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#7 {main} [] []
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the return types to **mixed**[] and **string**[] instead of array. It may fix the issue .